# Set background of a grid c# (wpf)

Tags: c#, wpf

Does anyone knows why this is wrong? The thing that doesn't work is the imageBrush.

```
   <Window x:Class="ProjectChallenge.Login"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Login" Height="403.3" Width="575.258">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="/bin/Debug/openboek.jpg"/>
        </Grid.Background>
        <TextBox x:Name="naamTextBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="144,139,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="196"/>
        <PasswordBox x:Name="passwordPasswordBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="144,179,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="196" Height="26"/>
        <Label x:Name="naamLabel" Content="Naam:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="74,139,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <Label x:Name="PasswordLabel" Content="Passwoord:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="74,179,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="0.545,2.154" />
        <Button x:Name="loginButton" Content="Log in" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="404,139,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="loginButton_Click"/>
        <Label Name="AccountLabel" Content="Nog geen account? Klik hier!" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="144,224,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="169" Height="35"/>
        <Label Content="Welkom!"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="116,78,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        <Button Name="sluitButton" Content="Sluiten" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="404,182,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="sluitButton_Click"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Elaborate please. What is wrong? Do you get any exception or does the image not show? :)

Comment: I get the error XamlParseException Occurred at line 3 (<imageBrush ImageSource ....)

Comment: I have tried the code an works fine. Could you post the whole xaml file?

Comment: It is probarbly because it can't find the image in the ImageSource. Have you tried adding a image to your project then right click it -> properties -> then change Copy to output Directory = Copy if newer?

Comment: That doesn't help. Above you find the whole xaml file.

Comment: See my answer, that should work I can guarantee that there is nothing wrong with your xaml except the image path :)

Comment: `Could not find a part of the path 'C:\bin\Debug\openboek.jpg'.` Is that the error you got? Always include full error details in the question.

Comment: You also have to update the path to wherever your image is. Probarbly like this: ImageSource="../openboek.jpg"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok,

I have tried the Xaml you postyed and it works fine. What you should do is right click project -> add -> Existing item -> (find your image). Then right click image -> Properties. then change "Copy to output Directory" to "Copy if newer". That should work.

You should also update the imagepath depending on where your image resides. If you just add to the project this would be the path: ImageSource="../openboek.jpg" If you add to an image folder: ImageSource="../Images/openboek.jpg"

as Clemens points out, this works, but the correct way is to just add the image and not change the "Copy to output Directory" property. The path should then be "/Images/openboek.jpg" (if you have it in a Images folder, which you should) See Holtermans answer

Comment: Don't do it this way. The answer given by Henk Holterman shows how you would show an image resource, which is usually better than having an external image file.

Comment: @Clemens Out of curiosity, when should you change the "Copy to output Directory" to copy if newer?

Comment: Not at all, unless you have good reason to have an external file. One case I can think of is when you need the abilty to replace the file at runtime.

Comment: Oh, I think Ill have to revisit some of my projects :S Don't know why I'am under the impression that I have to do that.Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Don't use an absolute path, WPF knows how to handle an image that is properly part of the project.

Add a Folder (Images) in your Solution Explorer, then "Add existing item" to add the picture to it. The build action should be set to "Resource" automatically.

Then simply use:

```
<ImageBrush ImageSource="/Images/openboek.jpg"/>
```